# Django REST Framework partial updates with depth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to enable partial update functionality in an app. I have extended the django auth user model to allow for some additional user data; when I send a PATCH request to the view (extending `rest_framework.generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView`), the correct data is received but it appears to ignore the nested data. Example:

```
{'id': 1, 'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux', 'user': {'username': 'user1', 'first_name': 'User', 'last_name': 'One'}}
```

`foo` and `baz` are properly updated, but `username`, `first_name`, and `last_name` are all ignored.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserProfileSerializer(many=False, read_only=False, partial=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'baz', 'yin', 'yang', 'user')
        depth = 1


class UserProfileGenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    queryset = Users.objects.all()

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        pass


class UserProfileView(UserinfoGenericAPIView, generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    pass
```

Can anybody tell me if partial updates even support depth and, if so, what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally answered in the question, but I feel it deserves a decent explanation.

**In Django REST Framework 3**, the process of saving nested data has been made considerably more clear. Now you can override `update` on the serializer and manipulate the `validated_data`, updating your model objects manually. This is [specifically documented now](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations), but the implementation is typically very specific to the situation.

---

Original answer (in the question) by [user2708386](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2708386/user2708386)

> Short answer is yes, it's possible. The problem was that I still needed to override the
>   `.save()` method on my model to also save the related User object.

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    foo = models.CharField()
    baz = models.CharField()
    yin = models.CharField()
    yang = models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_ = self.user
        user_.save(update_fields=('username', 'first_name', 'last_name'), **kwargs)

        return super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```